# Can a tag on the prey's leg harm a peregrine falcon if eaten?

Tags: birds, bird-behaviour, bird-feeding

I saw a bird (the mother) swallow the birdring of another bird it was eating on live camera (while feeding its chicks) [link](http://peregrinus.pl/pl/gdynia-pge-podglad) (the site is in Polish) and I am wondering whether:

- Can it actually cause harm or is it designed not to? (Researchers might have taken into account that the smaller birds could get eaten, when designing the tag)

Comment: Is this question on-topic here? [see SE-Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/327743/where-should-i-ask-questions-about-falcons)

Comment: I think this is on-topic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My research indicates that the answer is **no**.

[Chicago Exotics Animal Hospital](http://www.exoticpetvet.com/parrot-precautions.html) says:

> lead, zinc, copper, mercury and iron cause metal toxicosis if ingested
>   by birds.........................CAGES should be made of safe metal
>   with non-toxic paint,...............  Stainless steel is the safest
>   metal.

According to the [US Geological Survey](https://www.usgs.gov/centers/pwrc/science/about-federal-bird-bands):

There are three commonly used type of bird bands.  The lock-on type is used for birds with very strong beaks such as hawks and owls and

> The band is made of relatively soft aluminum and can be removed by the
>   bander, but not by the bird.

```
                                 and
```

> Rivet bands are made of harder metal than the lock-on band (but not
>   stainless steel) and are used on eagles.

The most commonly used band is the butt-end-band, and the source does not say what metal is used for this band ... but its picture looks like aluminum.  Bird bands come in many sizes, from hummingbird-sized to trumpeter swan sized

[ParrotForums.com](http://www.parrotforums.com/eclectus/32914-aluminum-toxic-not.html) says:

> Aluminum isn't toxic to birds. The only aluminum product that should
>   be watched for is aluminum foil as it contains tin (toxic to birds).